# How can I stop a connection from closing early?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to move a large amount of data from a mysql database (an amount larger than the max query size) and will need to run it through a loop in chunks to do so. The issue I am having is that even in the small sample size of 50 records, I am consistently missing about half of them as it seems the connection is being closed before the loops have finished. The code snippet I am having trouble with is below:

```
for(var j = 0; j < maxNum; j+=increment){
  // populates the array that can be used to find the mods that have been purchased
  console.log("START = " + j + " END = " + (j+increment));
  con.query("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id BETWEEN " + j
  + " AND " + (j + increment), function(err, rows, fields){
    if(!err){
      console.log("ROWS = " + rows.length);
      for(var a = 0; a < rows.length; a++){
        arrayOfObjs.push(rows[a]);
        console.log(rows[a].ID);
        // If the inner loop is at the end and the while loop is about to end this cycle
        if( (a + 1 == rows.length) && ((userCounter + increment - 1) > maxNum)) {
          // Loop through all the user objects and if it has records, add it to that item
          for(var b = 0; b < arrayOfUsers.length; b++){
            arrayOfUsers[b].objs = returnObjById(b, arrayOfMods);
            // If the loop is ending
            if(b+1 == arrayOfUsers.length){
              done1 = true;
              // temp force close
              shutDown()
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
}
```

The maxNum is supposed to represent the total number of users in the table as a whole, and the increment would be the size of the chunks. The returnObjs function does not call anything and is a simple switch that has no effect on the functionality. The shutDown function is a mysql connection end with a process.exit for a callback. That function is what is ending the script before it is finished but as I am new to Node, I do not know how I could adjust this in order to ensure that this does not continue to happen. Any suggestions would be appreciated as this is being done partly as a way to learn Node since it wouldn't be difficult to do in a language I'm familiar with.

Comment: It is probably because of your timeout value

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems here.

First, `conn.query()` is probably an async function (by looking at the callback function I see there). That means node won't wait for the callback to be called before continuing execution, resulting in your first loop iterations being executed all before even the first `conn.query()` callback is called.

I suggest you have a look at this excellent library : [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). It helps a lot with async operations, like in your case when you want to wait for the callback before starting another iteration. For that matter, the `async.series()` function may be helpful.

Secondly, you call to `shutdown()` seems to automatically happen when the last iteration of the third `for` loop has finished, but you are still in the first iteration of your first and second `for` loops. This means `j` will never be incremented, nor will `a`. The `shutdown()` function should be called at the end of the last iteration of your first `for` loop.

EDIT: I overlooked your `if` before the third `for` loop. I'm not sure what the purpose of the `(userCounter + increment - 1) > maxNum` check is, but if it prevents the third loop from being called when `a` or `j` are not at their max value, then you can discard my second point. The async problem is still there though, and is most likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: It's hard to notice with the nesting, but each one of those loops is only called once the previous loop is on its last run (when the counter is at the max allowable before breaking), so the shutDown function is only called after the first loop and the second loop have fully run their course. As far as async, I was definitely considering something like that but I wanted to see if there was some piece of knowledge I was missing about the language that would solve the issue without resorting to removing the async ability since that could be solved by just using php or python

Comment: That's what I noticed later :) So yeah, the problem is really that the first `for` finishes its iterations before the first callback is called, then during the first callback execution, the `shutdown()` function is called because it thinks it's the last iteration. With the async library, you can still keep the async nature of your code. Using `async.parallel()` (or `async.each()` if you just want to iterate over a collection) you can tell it to call a "final" callback once all your callbacks have finished executing. In that final async callback you could safely call `shutdown()`.